# How to derive an example of Riemannian submersion from $6$-dimensional sphere $S^{6}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

We are working on the geometry of Riemannian submersions from nearly Kaehler manifolds. We want to derive an example with domain as $6$-dimensional sphere $S^{6}$ (or from a non-Kaehlerian nearly Kaehler manifolds). Kindly give your valuable suggestions and references for the same. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: All submersions from $S^6$, with, say, connected fibers are trivial.  That is, they are of the form $S^6\rightarrow S^6$ for some diffeomorphism of $S^6$.  This is a consequence of the fact that $TS^6$ admits no non-trivial (orientable) sub-bundles, as can be seen using the Euler class.  I think if you allow disconnected fibers, all you get are double coverings $S^6\rightarrow X$.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason DeVito. Actually, we are looking for an example of slant conformal submersion from S^{6}. Can you please help us in this direction?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a slant conformal submersion is....